# knockout observable is not a function error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ecmascript-6

I'm exploring open-source dev and using yeoman and the knockout generator with crossroads and requirejs. I've looked at ES6 classes and constructors and I don't fully understand what is going on with knockout in certain situations where the observable isn't a function error is occurring in a ES6 class or function patterns. So I've seen this behavior with knockout previously but would like some additional details if I can.

A codepen here of this behaviour: http://codepen.io/srabeeh/pen/pjqweX?editors=001

Can someone explain what the source of the failed function lookup is?
Code:

```
    class Circle {
    constructor(diameter, quality) {
        this.diameter = ko.observable(diameter);
      this.quality = ko.observable(quality);
    }

  updateCircle(){
    console.log('updating...');
    // the correct way to update an observable
    // this line fails with diameter is not a function - uncomment to see error

    // this.diameter(this.diameter() +1);

    // this works but i fear this obliterates the observable
    this.diameter += 1;

    console.log(this.diameter); // gives NaN of course as it's an observable

    //function call fails that it's not a function 
    console.log(this.diameter());

    }

    startTimer(){
        var timer = setInterval(this.updateCircle, 1000)
    }
};

let c = new Circle(270, 5);
c.startTimer();
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if the this pointer correct in the updateCircle method? Else you might need to bind it.

Comment: off-topic but what's all this yoeman and things you don't understand and don't need? Get rid of all that cruft and start with the basics. Don't mess with things you don't understand. If you don't understand it, you don't need it. Don't use something unless you understand what it is and recognize your need for it. Don't try your hands at everything at once. Break it down and take it one thing at a time. Understand knockout on its own before jumping into ES6 and requirejs and yoeman and what's this crossroad stuff? I've never even heard of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually is a problem with your this pointer. Try this out:

```
class Circle {
  constructor(diameter, quality) {
    this.diameter = ko.observable(diameter);
    this.quality = ko.observable(quality);
  }

  updateCircle() {
    console.log('updating...');
    this.diameter(this.diameter() + 1);
    console.log(this.diameter());

  }

  startTimer() {
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
      this.updateCircle()
    }.bind(this), 1000)
  }
};

let c = new Circle(270, 5);
c.startTimer();
console.log("started")
```

Notice the bind.

Comment: I remember this gotcha. Reading up on "this" and "bind" again. Curious, is there a way to give the updateCircle() method the correct context or binding for "this" without changing the timer? For example a "var self = this;"? Is that a good pattern or is bind() the more prudent approach?

Comment: Yes it it. One way to find out how is to see what typescript compiles `setInterval(() => {this.doStuff()}), 1000)` since the lambda syntax always preserves the this state. - of course there are many other resources about the "this" issue to find. I personally like to stick to a transpile like typescript for all my js code.